# Alternative Idea to show $l^{\infty}$ is not seperable.

Tags: functional-analysis, separable-spaces

**We want to show ${l}^{\infty}$  not separable.**

(whereas usual ${l}^{\infty}$ denotes the set of all bounded sequences $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $\sup\limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}}|f(n)|<\infty $ and $||f-g|| = \sup\limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}}|f(n)-g(n)|)$

I have thought of an **alternative argument** to the problem and couldn't find something similar posted. Does the below argument work?

Claim: Every countable set $C \subseteq {l}^{\infty}$ is not dense in ${l}^{\infty}$ .

Idea: Suppose $C = \{f_1,f_2,...\}$ is a countable subset of  ${l}^{\infty}$. Then define $g\in {l}^{\infty}$ using the diagonilzation argument where

\begin{equation}
g(n)=
    \begin{cases}
        -1 & \text{if } f_n(n)\geq 0\\
        1 & \text{if } f_n(n)< 0
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Clearly $g\in {l}^{\infty}$. Also we see that for each $n$ we have $||f_n-g||\geq 1$, since $|f_n(n)-g(n)|\geq 1$. And we can conclude  $C$ is not dense.

Comment: Yes, thank you!